# S01E10: How did Romero know about the money?

Tags: plot-explanation, bates-motel

In the TV series [Bates Motel (2013)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2188671), sheriff Alex Romero retrieved the money from Shelby's garage.

**How did he know about it?** Was he involved in their slavery empire? If yes, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sheriff Romero cares about the town and he's not part of the slavery business**

Shelby has Abernathy's money ($ 150,000 I think) and Abernathy knows about the fact that Shelby and Norma are in a relationship and believes that Shelby gave the money to Norma. So, Abernathy threatens Norma that she and her sons will be killed if money is not delivered to him by midnight.

Norma goes to Sheriff Romero and explains her situation that she doesn't have the money and about the threat. Romero is clever enough to understand that Shelby has Abernathy's money and tells her that no harm will come to her or her sons. So, he goes to Shelby's house and searches for the money and finds it.

And at the end of the episode, it's made clear when Romero shoots Abernathy and throws bag full of money into the river that Sheriff Romero is not involved in any illegal business and cares for his town.